# Notation for the predecessor of an ordinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, ordinals

I'm reading something on ordinal numbers and I have a silly notational doubt on them.

From a notational point of view, if $\gamma$ is a non limit ordinal, does the notation $\gamma-1$ make sense in order to denote the precedessor of $\gamma$? I'm asking this because I would define a sequence of sets of the form $X_\alpha=\Gamma(X_{\alpha-1})$ when $\alpha$ is non limit and $X_\alpha=\bigcup\limits_{\beta <\alpha} \Gamma(X_\beta)$ (here $\Gamma$ is a given function!), and I'm not sure that such a definition is correct, unless I do not assume the possibility of denoting the predecessor of $\gamma$ as $\gamma-1$.

Comment: If you want to denote it like that, sure you can. But you can always say $X_{\alpha+1} = \Gamma(X_{\alpha})$.

Comment: It makes sense. However, I don't see that it's worthwhile. t looks like $0$ qualifies as a limit ordinal for purposes of this definition, so $X_0 = \emptyset$.  Easier to just define the successor/non-limit case using successor, as is customary: $X_{\alpha + 1} = \Gamma(X_{\alpha})$